# pcsxr FF9 cheats

Tags: linux, cheats, final-fantasy-9, pcsxr

I'm running FF9 (PS1 pal version) in pcsxr under linux. I want make it a little bit easier for me.

I found [this](https://www.neoseeker.com/final-fantasy-ix/gameshark/psx/) I have no idea how the form is to use this cheats.

What I know is I have to copy in my

```
$HOME/.pcsxr/cheats/
```

and then activate it over the pcxr gui. but I have no Idea if I have to respect some special form for the cheat file.

Is it working like  [this](https://forum.clockworkpi.com/t/cheats-for-pcsx-standalone/4229) ? but what means `Cheat name` Is this a placeholder?